# UITextfield disappears when touch it

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Can someone tell me why my UITextField disappears when I tap on it ?

[image]

Comment: We will need some code here...

Comment: I just add a textfield to my storyboard

Comment: Is there any animation ? Are you implementing some textfield's delegate methods ?

Comment: I simply add a UITextfield to my storyboard without any implementations

Comment: I would try creating another project and adding a textfield ..  see if the it happens again